# Do FOL theorem provers accept axiom schemata?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, automated-theorem-proving

Axiom schemata (such as ZFC) are, in a sense, infinite sets of axioms. Do the ATPs designed to work with FOL (such as Vampire) accept axiom schemata?

I looked in the Vampire ["manual"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Elaurako/pub/CAV13_Kovacs.pdf) briefly, but couldn't answer this question. Is this possible? How would one do it in TPTP syntax? Are problems involving axiom schemata part of the [CASC FOF](http://www.tptp.org/CASC/26/Design.html#CompetitionDivisions) division?